# On a HTML Edit form, what is a good approach to have both reset and remember the posted values features?

Tags: forms

I have a form which has both server side and client side validation.
It is an edit form, so the original user values are originally pre-populated.

```
e.g. The original pre-populated values are:
username = yeo
surname = yang
phonenumber = 11-12345
```

Now, the user edits to the below and submits.

```
e.g. The edited submitted values are:
username = yeoNew
surname = yangNew
phonenumber = 12-1111
```

This gets submitted to the serverside and fails the serverside validation because the phonenumber starting with 12 is not allowed.

Anyway, so the form is displayed back to the user as

```
e.g. The redisplayed form values are:
username = yeoNew
surname = yangNew
phonenumber = 12-1111
```

This is because my form allows the user to remember their submitted values.

At this stage, I'd like to allow the user to have the ability to reset the form values to the original values using clientside javascript. This is like a reset feature.

```
e.g. The reset button will restore the form values to:
username = yeo
surname = yang
phonenumber = 11-12345
```

The reason for this reset feature is that I want the user to have the option to edit the phonenumber again from the original values.

My question is: 
What is a good way to keep track of the original values within the HTML so that I can restore it with javascript?

I'm thinking a new attribute called orig='' within the form elements which will store this value.
Is that a good idea?
Any other approaches?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the HTML5 local storage. 
See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Using jquery I would do it this way:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function load() {
        if (localStorage["username"]) {
            $('#username').val(localStorage["username"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["surname"]) {
            $('#surname').val(localStorage["surname"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["phone"]) {
            $('#phone').val(localStorage["phone"]);
        }
      }

      function save() {
        localStorage["username"] =  $('#username ').val();
        localStorage["surname"] =  $('#surname').val();
        localStorage["phone"] =  $('#phone').val();
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: Hi, that is an interesting and new solution. I have decided to go with my original idea. However your solution is food for thought. Cheers